# Unity exception interception - configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I would like to have one set of interceptors at the MVC or Web API layer that catch any exception, grab the URI that generated the exception, and look up the message back to the user from configuration.

For example a POST to /api/v1/user that throws a unique constraint violation would be configured to respond "User already exists", while the same exception for POST /api/v1/vehicle would respond "VIN is already in system".

Is there any facility in Unity for this?  If not, does anyone have examples from publicly available source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is not quite right tool for customizing error responses in ASP.NET applications. It's a Dependency Injection container and you want it to just instantiate your controller with all required dependencies. It's a bad idea to mix it with application logic (and customizing error responses is certainly the part of it).

ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API provide an extensibility point suited for exactly what you need - Exception Filters. Here is a sample for ASP.NET Web API:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //  Add  your exception handling here

        //  Check context.Exception and decide whether you need to handle it
        if (context.Exception is SqlException)
        {
            var controllerType = context.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType();

            if (controllerType == typeof(UserController))
            {
                context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("User already exists")
                };
            }
            else
            {
                // Cover other controller types here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see implementation is fair straightforward. Inside `OnException()` method you have an access to exception itself with controller and action contexts.
If your logic requires that this exception should be handled for this controller action, you just fill `context.Response` with appropriate `HttpResponseMessage`, selecting HTTP status code and the body.

You can apply such exception filter globally with

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

in your `WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config)` or on controller level:

```
[CustomExceptionFilter]
public class UserController : ApiController
```

Implementation will be very similar for ASP.NET MVC. In that case your filter should implement `System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter`.